# Mediawiki MobileFrontEnd extension error

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have installed the MobleFrontEnd extension in my wiki. It was working perfectly. But after installing some other extension, I updated wiki for updating the new tables to the database. After that clicking on "Mobile view" in the footer gives me an error:    `'Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /home/wiki/html/includes/HtmlFormatter.php on line 66`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

The error:

### Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding()

was because of the absence of **php Multibyte Support** in the server.

By installing  `php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm`and **restarting** apache solved the issue.

**DONT FORGET TO RESTART APACHE.** Because I wasted a lot of time without the restart.